# How to check if email is verified in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
$("#btnContinue").on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // <== disable form submit


const email = signupForm['signup-email'].value;
const password = signupForm['signup-password'].value;


// sign up the user & add firestore data
const auth = firebase.auth();
const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
promise.then(user => {
  user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  user.sendEmailVerification();
}).catch(error => console.log);

});
```

Hello everyone, my idea is that if the user signs in with email and password, the website sendes him a verifcation email. The problem that Idon't know how check if the Email is verified.Something like if Email is verified consol.log("Email is verified"). I'm thankfull for every Help and Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

on user you will get a property `emailVerified: boolean` which inform about verification status
[docs link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User#emailverified)